# Pandas dataframe. Eliminating rows matching certain conditions in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following table:

```
Days   Age  Sex
5      39   F
NaN    54   M
4      26   M
1      42   M
4      29   M
```

I want to count separately mean value of days for men and women, but taking only those rows where I have 3 days or more. (Eliminating all the missing values and everything that is <3 in column "Days")

I was thinking of something like:

```
df.groupby("Sex")["Days"].mean().where()....
```

where column[0] >= 3
But have problems with "where" condition

What will be the best command to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about?

```
df.query("Days > 2").groupby("Sex")["Days"].mean()
```

Demo:

```
In [208]: df
Out[208]:
   Days  Age Sex
0   5.0   39   F
1   NaN   54   M
2   4.0   26   M
3   1.0   42   M
4   4.0   29   M

In [209]: df.query("Days > 2").groupby("Sex")["Days"].mean()
Out[209]:
Sex
F    5.0
M    4.0
Name: Days, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!